# Setting tab is not available in data table properties

Tags: spotfire

I am trying to edit settings tab under data table properties in order to set data on-demand properties.

How can we edit setting tab.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Please see this document from Spotfire:
https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire/7.0.1/doc/html/add/add_on_demand_overview.htm

Data on Demand can only be set for Information Links or for Data Tables from a Data Connection. If you are using a Spreadsheet, Direct Connection, or other source, the settings tab will be disabled.